# Rails - exclude some url form routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dont know how to tell this. I have my site on url like:

```
www.mysite.com
```

I want to have some other "stuff" on url:

```
www.mysite.com/some/mystuff
```

How can i hm exclude this url from rails app? When i put this url in browser it tells me that there is no such page. Is this possible?

Comment: My best guess is that you must use something like [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main).

Comment: ok thanks i thinks soo to because my phpmyadmin works like that

Answer (score 0):

Inside config/routes.rb, you could add:

```
match "*missing" => redirect("/")
```

This will redirect any unknown urls directly to the homepage. Also, you could create the famous Error 404 page and redirect to it.

```
match "*missing" => 'application#404'
```

ApplicationController:

```
def 404
    render: 'home/404'
end
```

Comment: thats not bad but i need to run some php script in this url soo this wont work in my example